# Adjusting max battery percentage due to wear 19.10

Tags: battery, 19.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my laptop. However, the battery percentage displayed in the default DE appears to top out at the maximum capacity of the battery after wear leveling (Around 91%). Is there a way to set the max capacity of the battery as "full"?